# Could you explain the meaning of each element in config file(mac os) which connected to AWS instance with ssh

Tags: macos, amazon-web-services, ssh

I am a new one to AWS service. Now, I have launched an instance in AWS named retest_den01. I want to connect it with `ssh` (mac os). I have a config file which is shown as following. Could you tell me how to get the host in AWS, what's the difference of `Host` and `HostName`. In addition, the meaning of `ProxyCommand ssh -W %h:%p gateway`.

```
Host gateway
  HostName 54.199.245.48
  User ec2-user
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/ei-d.pem
  ServerAliveInterval 120

Host rmtest_den01
  HostName 172.31.19.179
  User ec2-user
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/ei-cloud.pem
  ProxyCommand ssh -W %h:%p gateway
  ServerAliveInterval 120
  StrictHostKeyChecking no
  UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null
  LocalForward 30383 localhost:30383
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of that is precisely explained in the manual page for `ssh_config` (good read to start!). But the the respective questions:

> Could you tell me how to get the host in AWS

`ssh rmtest_den01` should take you to your instance.

> what's the difference of `Host` and `HostName`

`Host is start of the conditional block, evaluating only if the host you are using on the command-line matches the value next to that option.

`HostName` is the actual IP address or hostname your client is going to connect to.

> In addition, the meaning of `ProxyCommand ssh -W %h:%p gateway`.

This means that to your hosts IP you can not connect directly from public internet, but only through the intermediate server `gateway`, which has its configuration above.

See my edit. The indentation does not matter, but helps to understand what is related to what.